# "Classical" approach to local class field theory (Brauer group and Hasse invariant)

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I'm trying to learn local class field theory from the corresponding chapter of [Lorenz's "Algebra 2"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-72488-1), which, according to its mission statement, takes a more classical approach

> [Local class field theory] admits of a remarkably simple demonstration based on the algebra-theoretic results of the previous chapter [crossed products and the Hasse invariant]. This proof, though very satisfying in several regards and dating back to H. Hasse and E. Noether, is apparently lesser known than it deserves to be.

This chapter, though very informative, is tough, so I was hoping to find some **supplemental sources**. One such text I've found is Guillot's "A Gentle Introduction to Local Class Field Theory", however while it's very similar on the surface, it seems to go off in a different direction in the chapters on CFT proper, concentrating more on Galois cohomology, while Lorenz takes a more elementary approach.

Comment: See also [Local class field theory is easy](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(75)90156-5) by Hazewinkel

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584352/group-cohomology-or-classical-approach-for-class-field-theory

Comment: @lhf thanks for the suggestions, but these seem nothing like what I'm looking for.